# Writing events for dynamically generated checkbox in a table

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a page where there is a dynamically generated table with the last column which has checked checkboxes.The final bill is shown below the table. As i uncheck the checkboxes the amount should decrease in the final table.So i have to know which corresponding checkbox was clicked in the same row as the amount.

```
package com.example.shopkart;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class checkout extends Activity {
    datamanager dm;
    String name,mailid;
    int bill=0;
    TableLayout tbcheckout;
    TextView txtbill;
    int[] amount_product;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkout);
        dm=new datamanager(this);
        tbcheckout=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbcheckout);
        txtbill=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtbill);
        name=getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        mailid=getIntent().getExtras().getString("mailid");
        try {
            viewtable();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
    public void viewtable() throws SQLException
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> data=dm.getAllRowsAsArrays1(mailid);
        amount_product=new int[data.size()];
        TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(this);
        TextView tv0 = new TextView(this);
        tv0.setText(" Product Name ");
        tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));
        tbrow0.addView(tv0);
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText(" Product Price ");
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));
        tbrow0.addView(tv1);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(" Pay Now ");
        tv2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));
        tbrow0.addView(tv2);
        tbcheckout.addView(tbrow0);
        for (int position=0; position < data.size(); position++)
        {
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(this);
            ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);

            TextView t1v = new TextView(this);
            t1v.setText(row.get(0).toString());
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);

            TextView t2v = new TextView(this);
            t2v.setText(row.get(1).toString());
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
            amount_product[position]=Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString());
            bill+=Integer.parseInt(row.get(1).toString());

            CheckBox cb1=new CheckBox(this);
            cb1.setText("Include");

            cb1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B0082"));   
            cb1.setChecked(true);
            tbrow.addView(cb1);

            tbcheckout.addView(tbrow);

        }
        txtbill.setText("Your final cart amount is Rs "+bill);

        }


}
```

I placed the amounts of each item in an array so that i can refer them later.How do i refer to the corresponding checkbox and write event for them?

Comment: link to screenshot may help to understand the situation easily. Provide the link if you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You should set the `setonCheckedChangeListener()` ,like this

```
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

In your Activity `checkout`

`public class checkout extends Activity implements OnCheckChangedListener`

Implement here

```
  @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Object tag=buttonView.getTag();
        //could be integer, or primitive datatype
        //just make sure of type-casting
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic, reduce value in final table or such
        }

    }
```

2.Next set tag to checkbox, for more reference see here [setTag(Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
   cb1.setTag(anyObject);
```

which can be used to get some value on object to perform any operation ,which in this case is to reduce value in final table.

Comment: Where do i write the listener method for the event??

Comment: already updated code, once you implement `OnCheckChangedListener` in your activity, it will tell you to override and provide implementation in your checkout activity , see to that, hope it helps

Comment: can i set cb1.setTag(position) ?? and how do i retrieve the tag in the listener???

Comment: yes you can and use the position to get from ArrayList, is the previous problem resolved?? Please accept the answer!!